# C# string format for multiple languages

Tags: c#

I am trying format for English characters and Chinese characters left and right alignment

Because Chinese characters are different width i cant align with string.format

Example:

```
String.Format("{0,-40}{1,8}", "some string", $20.00);
String.Format("{0,-40}{1,8}", "些字符串些字符串些字符串些字符串", $20.00);
String.Format("{0,-40}{1,8}", "些", $20.00);
String.Format("{0,-40}{1,8}", "a", $20.00);


|------------------------------total char 48 char always-------------|



-------------name 40 char maximum ---------- | -price 8 char always-

some string                                                     $20.00

些字符串些字符串些字符串些字符串                                  $15.00

些                                                               $8.00

a                                                              $100.00
```

Any help? with multiple language formatting?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of offsetting the strings with composite formatting, you should use the tabulations in order to deal with this problem. Their main purpose is to create a uniform spacing between columns of strings with a mismatching length. Here is how:

```
String s1 = String.Format("{0}\t\t\t\t{1}", "some string", "$20.00");
String s2 = String.Format("{0}\t\t\t\t{1}", "一些字符串", "$20.00");
String s3 = String.Format("{0}\t\t\t\t{1}", "some 一些字符串", "$20.00");
```

The output of the above example would be:

```
some string                   $20.00
一些字符串                     $20.00
some 一些字符串                $20.00
```

Visit [this link](http://rextester.com/JYNO72241) for a working demo.

Comment: Thank you but if Chinese string is long and English short, how i can calculate tabulations ? example English is "item" Chinese is "些字符串些字符串些字符串" maximum length for row is 47 characters and right price must be  align  to right

Comment: Mh... you are right... you may try to find the longest string in the first column and then pad all of them using that value (`10` for example): `{0,-10}\t\t\t\t{1}`. This should create a sort of safety threshold.

Comment: Nope is not working because Chinese char length is 10 , English length is 10 but Chinese string is longer because width of char

Answer (score 0):

I think the formatting depends on the font used. But if you know the font, you can measure it directly, something like:

```
public string padString(string s, Graphics g, Font f, float desiredWidth, float spaceWidth)
{
    float orig = g.MeasureString(s, f).Width;
    int spaceCount = (int)Math.Max(0, (desiredWidth - orig) / spaceWidth);
    return s + new string(' ', spaceCount) + '\t';
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        Font f = textBox1.Font;
        float tabWidth = g.MeasureString("x\t\t\tx", f).Width - g.MeasureString("x\t\tx", f).Width;
        float spaceWidth = g.MeasureString("x   x", f).Width - g.MeasureString("x  x", f).Width;
        float dw = tabWidth * 5.5f; // half of the tab is on purpose

        String s1 = String.Format("{0}{1,8}", padString("some string", g, f, dw, spaceWidth), "$20.00");
        String s2 = String.Format("{0}{1,8}", padString("些字符串些字符串些字符串些字符串", g, f, dw, spaceWidth), "$20.00");
        String s3 = String.Format("{0}{1,8}", padString("些", g, f, dw, spaceWidth), "$20.00");
        String s4 = String.Format("{0}{1,8}", padString("a", g, f, dw, spaceWidth), "$20.00");

        textBox1.AppendText(s1 + "\n");
        textBox1.AppendText(s2 + "\n");
        textBox1.AppendText(s3 + "\n");
        textBox1.AppendText(s4 + "\n");
    }
}
```

Or you can choose font that is more predictable (like chinese character is twice the width of English) and calculate the width directly.

Comment: Thank you so much i will try this one, this text goes to printer that is why i need spec char for printer paper, also this text should be right format in WPF TextBlock, thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed a font problem. I faced this issue where my output to a WPF textbox looked like this

```
非收入服务费                        $0.0
折扣                     0          $0.0
退回项                   0          $0.0
更正合计                 0          $0.0
贷项合计                            $0.0
费用总计                           $42.6
```

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48970839/15766965 ,choosing a font where Chinese symbols scales well with the size of latin characters may help here. ( i.e. width taken by Chinese symbol is twice or some integer multiple of width taken by latin character).

These fonts worked for me

1. SimSun
2. SimSun-ExtB

Now, it should be possible to tweak the padding logic and obtain the desired column width.
In the Q, first column width is 40 chars, so if we have 4 Chinese symbols then number of spaces required is:

```
40 - (2)*4 = 32
```

(Assuming each Chinese symbol takes twice the width of normal character)

Separate logic is needed to count the total number of Chinese symbols in a string which occupy more width.