# Text alignment issue when using non-alphanumeric characters like Japanese, Chinese, Thai, etc

Tags: c#, fonts, alignment

I have a simple report written in C# where I print out text file, I have a problem when it's a non alphanumerics characters. Please take a look at the sample below.

```
Johnny    $1000
Adam      $1000
测测        $1000
```

You can see that `Johnny` and `Adam` line perfectly, but not the `测测` characters. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970165/c-sharp-string-format-for-multiple-languages

Comment: It depends on how/where you're printing. If you are in a Graphics context,  `TextRenderer.DrawText()` or `Graphics.DrawString()` lets you position the rendered text at pixel precision. Otherwise, expand tabs with "\t" (with some luck you'll get there, sometimes).

Comment: @hce: thanks man. Exactly what I need.

Comment: You may also find MeasureString useful...  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58(v=vs.110).aspx