# Alignment issue when string contains non-alphanumeric characters like Chinese or Japanese

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on small program written in C# where it will it will query the result from the Database and show it in text file format.

I have a problem when the result contains non-alphanumeric characters. Please take a look at the sample below.

```
Johnny    $1000
Adam      $1000
测测        $1000
```

You can see that `Johnny` and `Adam` line perfectly, but not the `测测` characters. I've seen this thread

[C# string format for multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970165/c-sharp-string-format-for-multiple-languages)

And it's actually possible to line it up using `Tab` instead of `Space`, but how do I calculate tabs needed because alphabet and chinese/japanese has different width. And I have to do it inside SQL, means that I cannot use something like `MeasureString`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In SQL, this would not be a problem because you'd be selecting these values as columns. Formatting strings in SQL Server 2008 is an exercise in suffering, which is why you want to leave presentation concerns to the client. As your client is C#, it can certainly do that, so any reason you "have" to do it inside SQL?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to do it in C# level, it has to be from SQL. I was thinking is there any way to check how many chinese/japanese characters in a string in SQL? I could probably count the total number of non-alphabet in a string and apply the tab from there.

Comment: There's not really any solid, reliable way to do this outside the presentation layer. The number of spaces (or visual tabs) needed to line up `测测` depends on the optical width of the characters, which in turn relies on the font used to render it. You can't tell from the character alone if it's going to be "wide" and needs extra characters. "Non-alphabet" isn't really helpful either since SQL has no functions for Unicode categories. You can't get much more alphabetic than "αβ", and in most fonts this would be just as wide as "ab", but `α` and `β` are not in the alphanumerical set `a-z0-9`.

Comment: Hi, do you have found methods to align them?

Answer (score 0):

@warheat1990: I am afraid that @Jeroen is right with his comment.
If you are supposed to use SQL you may try to choose a font which is predictable (like chinese character is twice the width of English) and calculate the width directly.
So any chinese/japanese character would occupy twice the space as an english character would.